# How can I enforce restrictions on an object's description via e.g. a hash?

Tags: regex, perl, hash, perl-module, perl-data-structures

If I have a hash that "describes" attributes of objects i.e. names and types like:

```
{  
  column_defs => {  
          serial_id    => { type => INTEGER     },  
          first_name   => { type => CHAR(40) },  
          salary       => { type => DOUBLE }, 
      },   
}
```

The actual hash might be changed but I don't think that the definition affects my core question.
What is a good way to check if the types of each field is defined correctly? E.g. that `salary` is not defined `FLOAT` or serial_id is not string etc. (but what should or should not be should be configurable)
I am not sure what would be the best way to define these actual "restrictions" and how to apply them on the hash.

Comment: The next isn't very fast way, but worth. Learn about the `Moose` and his [attributes](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/Attributes.pod) and [types](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/Types.pod). You will get a free type checking and much more for your objects...

Comment: @jm666:The object I am refering to are not perl objects. I just "parse" some definitions from a text file and want to validate them. The example I posted could be a representation of the definition

Comment: Your question is pretty broad without showing a sample of the actual data you're trying to validate. Are you saying the file contains rows like `salary DOUBLE`? Or are they more like `salary 100.123`?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot:Exactly as you said `salary DOUBLE`. I.e. it contains (part of it) such kind of "declarations"/descriptions and I want to validate it. I thought to just create another hash and try comparing keys but I thought there might be another better approach more suitable in perl (I don't have a good background in perl TBH)

Comment: So why not just compare the strings in the file and the strings in the hash for equality while parsing the file?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want to do string comparison between values in a file and values in a hash:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %column_defs = (
    serial_id  => { type => 'INTEGER' },
    first_name => { type => 'CHAR(40)' },
    salary     => { type => 'DOUBLE' },
);

while (<DATA>) {
    my ($column, $type) = split;
    if (my $def = $column_defs{$column}) {
        say "'$column' should be $def->{type} but is $type" if $def->{type} ne $type;
    }
}

__DATA__
salary     DOUBLE
serial_id  FLOAT
first_name CHAR(20)
foo        BAR
```

Note that for simplicity, I made the column definitions from your snippet into their own hash.

#### Output:

```
'serial_id' should be INTEGER but is FLOAT
'first_name' should be CHAR(40) but is CHAR(20)
```

Comment: Not quite. 1) The column_defs hash is what will be actually read. 2) The actual validation rules and where should they be kept/stored and loaded are the core of my problem. In your example you used the input as the validation rule (which validation rule I would like it to be configurable i.e. not part of code preferably)

Comment: If you're not validating the file, what exactly *are* you validating? It is completely unclear to me what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Misread the question, or rather, didn't see the relevant comment until it was too late - doh! This answer is for checking the values of the fields conform to the specs. Maybe you'll want to do that later! ;-)

You can do this kind of checking manually by setting up tests for the different types of data you're looking at and then running them on the data, e.g.

```
## tests
sub integer {
    return 1 if $_[0] =~ /^[0-9]+$/;
    return 0;
}
sub string {
    return 1 if $_[0] =~ /^[\w\s]+$/;
    return 0;
}
sub char_40_ {
    return 1 if length($_[0]) <= 40;
    return 0;
}
sub double {
   (etc.)
...
# set up a dispatch hash
my %d_hash = (
    serial_id => \&integer,
    first_name => \&char_40_,
    salary => \&double,
    another_field => \&integer,
    more_data => \&string,
);
```

Then you can check that the data in the fields matches the specs by calling the appropriate sub:

```
$d_hash{ $field_name }->( $value_of_field )
```

Depending on how many different `type`s of data you're looking at, and the number of each, you may want to set up specific tests, e.g. CHAR(40) runs a specific test for fields of 40 chars or less, or you could parse the type field and apply a test for CHARs and for length 40 or less.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I'm not 100% clear what you're asking, but perhaps something like this might be helpful...?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Types::Standard qw( Dict );
use Types::XSD::Lite qw( String Integer Float );

my $check = Dict[
  serial_id   => Integer,
  first_name  => String[ maxLength => 40 ],
  salary      => Float,
];

$check->assert_valid({
  serial_id   => 999,
  first_name  => "Alice",
  salary      => 20_000.00,
});

$check->assert_valid({
  serial_id   => 999,
  first_name  => "Bob",
  salary      => "peanuts",  # fails
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear what you're asking...

When you define an *object*, you're suppose to use your methods to verify an object. Here's a very simple example:

```
package Local::Employee;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp;
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);
use feature qw(say state);

sub new {
    my $class       = shift;
    my $first_name  = shift;
    my $salary      = shift;

    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $class;

    $self->serial;
    $self->first_name( $first_name );
    $self->salary( $salary );
    return $self;
}

sub serial {
    my $self        = shift;
    my $bad_boy     = shift;

    state $serial   = 0;
    if ( defined $bad_boy ) {
        croak( qq(Cannot set serial number. You can only retrieve it.) );
    }
    if ( not exists $self->{SERIAL} ) {
        $self->{SERIAL} = sprintf "%04d", ++$serial;
    }
    return $self->{SERIAL};
}

sub first_name {
    my $self        = shift;
    my $first_name  = shift;

    if ( defined $first_name ) {
        if ( length $first_name > 40 ) {
            croak( qq(First name can't be longer than forty characters.) );
        }
        $self->{FIRST_NAME} = $first_name;
    }
    return $self->{FIRST_NAME};
}

sub salary {
    my $self        = shift;
    my $salary      = shift;

    if ( defined $salary ) {
        if ( not looks_like_number $salary ) {
            croak( qq(Salary must be numeric) );
        }
        $self->{SALARY} = $salary;
    }
    return $self->{SALARY};
}

sub employee {
    my $self        = shift;

    my %employee_hash = %{ $self };
    return \%employee_hash;
}
1;
```

Notice that each of my methods verify their data. Also notice that my `new` constructor doesn't know how the data itself is stored. It merely calls the methods for each piece of data. You can *bless* an object and use the various methods before you return the object to the main program.

Also notice that if I return the whole structure, I dereference my hash reference, and then return *that* hash reference. In other words, when I return my structure, you get a copy of that structure and not the structure itself. Futzing with `$employee->{NAME}` isn't going to change the actual name of the object.

Is this totally protected? No. A bad player could use `Data::Dumper`, get the structure of my object, and then set `$self->{NAME} = $name` instead of calling `$self->name($name)`. There is a concept of [Inside-Out Objects](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/UnixReview/col63.html), but most developers have agreed it's more trouble than it's worth. Makes debugging really difficult.

---

Maybe what you want is more *flexibility*, you want to define an object's structure on the fly, and verify it.

Take a close look at all of my methods, and you can see they're all very similar in how they work. I could almost create a template. In fact, there are template classes like [Class::Struct](http://perldoc.perl.org/Class/Struct.html) that allow you to create classes on the fly. `Class::Struct` defines subroutines that act as methods based upon your field names and puts those subroutines in a namespace you've defined as you class. If you have a class called `Foo` with a method `bar`, a subroutine called `Foo::bar` will be defined, and of course it will also create a subroutine `Foo::new` to use as a constructor. Once you've defined a class, you can use it just like a normal class:

```
my $foo = Foo->new(-bar => "bar value");
say "The value of bar is: " . $foo->bar";
```

If I were you, I wouldn't bother to create *real* classes because it's rather complex. Instead, I would have a class that allows me to create other *classes*.

[Autoloading](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Autoloading) is a way of defining a single subroutine called `AUTOLOAD` that allows you to implement multiple methods without you having to define each and every one. When you call a method like this:

```
$employee->first_name("Bob");
```

Perl looks through your subroutines for one named `first_name`. If it can't find one, it looks for one called `AUTOLOAD` and sends it the parameters and sets `$AUTOLOAD` to the name of the *method* being called.

Let's say you have a hash of *classes* that contains two classes, one `employee` and one `car`:

```
$VAR = {
       "employee"   =>  "FIELDS"  => {
           "first_name" => "string:40",
           "serial"     => "serial:d09",
           "salary"     => "float:%8.2f",
       }
       {
       "cars"      => "FIELDS"   => {
           "license"     => "string:9",
           "make"        => "string:20",
           "model"       => "string:20",
           "top_speed"   => "integer:4",
       }
}
```

Now imagine a way to create a new class like this:

```
     my $employee = Local::Class->new( "employee", {
              -first_name => "Bob",
              -salary     => 342.95,
          },
    );

    my $car = Local::Class->new( "car", {
            -make         => "Chevy",
            -model        => "Lumina",
            -engine       => "1.2",
       },
   );
```

You could use your `new` constructor subroutine to set all of those *fields* via the `AUTOLOAD` subroutine. Once done, you can treat each object as a class. Let's say you want to know the name of the employee:

```
 say "The employee's name is " . $employee->name;
```

This could be handled by an `AUTOLOAD` subroutine that sees what type of *class* employee is, then verifies if `name` is even a valid method. If it is, it returns the value of that hash key. Let's take a look at setting:

```
 $employee->name("Bob, the one and true King of France. All hale his majesty");
```

It again uses `AUTOLOAD` to verify that `name` is a valid field, and that the value you're setting is a valid name. (In this case, the subroutine will croak with a name too long error).

Is that more what you want to do? You'll have to have a way of creating your class hash, and making sure that it cannot be changed once set. Then, you simply have to be able to use that hash to verify each object you're creating.

Comment: Fantastically detailed explanation. It's a shame the question wasn't clearer! :\